# Side Menu alpha not working over body tag

Tags: javascript, css

I have a side navigation menu on my site. When pressed, it calls a JavaScript function that changes the alpha channel of the body tag. For some reason only part of the screen's alpha channel is changing (section, img, bootstrap containers are not). The section tag has a class that gives it a background color, I'm thinking this might be the issue. Which would be the smart way to get this working?

This is the code I'm using for the alpha management:

```
/* Set the width of the side navigation to 250px */
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "350px";
    document.body.style.background = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
}

/* Set the width of the side navigation to 0 */
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
     document.body.style.background = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
}
```

The html goes like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Cripto Frog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rammetto+One" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
    <script src="sidebar.js"></script>
</head>
<main>
    <header>
    <span class="menu_burger" onclick="openNav()"><i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i></i></span>
    <img src="img/frog.jpg" alt="">
    </header>

        <body>

            <!-- Side Menu -->
            <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
              <a href="people.html">TOP_TEN_COINS</a>
              <a href="#">ALT_COINS</a>
              <a href="#">WHITE_PAPERS</a>
              <a href="#">YOUTUBERS</a>
              <a href="#">EXCHANGES</a>
              <a href="#">NEWS_SITES</a>
              <a href="#">CONTACTO</a>
              <section class="nav_divididor"></section>
              <section class="nav_footer">hlkjhlkjhlk</section>
            </div>




            <section class="primera_section"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam doloremque excepturi molestias aut fuga ullam aliquid minus dolores voluptatem non, beatae placeat soluta libero eos et delectus nemo minima iusto.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi error aspernatur officiis, sint fugiat unde quos labore laborum cupiditate voluptates, totam sunt ut quod praesentium omnis et consequuntur sapiente incidunt?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit iure eveniet a voluptas cumque! Eos qui, iusto neque, fugit praesentium totam soluta eius laudantium cupiditate dolorem dignissimos ut minus veritatis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla earum soluta nesciunt dicta officia reprehenderit autem, molestias explicabo et accusamus, officiis nostrum cumque perspiciatis suscipit veniam molestiae fuga tenetur modi!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate itaque atque molestiae, id fugit, quidem hic rem cum praesentium dolor perspiciatis nostrum sapiente enim corrupti doloremque aliquam voluptas cumque omnis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam iusto dolor nostrum voluptate quos consectetur facere, quia, earum non, tenetur, officia laboriosam cumque suscipit itaque nobis obcaecati. Facilis veritatis, repudiandae.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam doloremque excepturi molestias aut fuga ullam aliquid minus dolores voluptatem non, beatae placeat soluta libero eos et delectus nemo minima iusto.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi error aspernatur officiis, sint fugiat unde quos labore laborum cupiditate voluptates, totam sunt ut quod praesentium omnis et consequuntur sapiente incidunt?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit iure eveniet a voluptas cumque! Eos qui, iusto neque, fugit praesentium totam soluta eius laudantium cupiditate dolorem dignissimos ut minus veritatis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla earum soluta nesciunt dicta officia reprehenderit autem, molestias explicabo et accusamus, officiis nostrum cumque perspiciatis suscipit veniam molestiae fuga tenetur modi!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate itaque atque molestiae, id fugit, quidem hic rem cum praesentium dolor perspiciatis nostrum sapiente enim corrupti doloremque aliquam voluptas cumque omnis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam iusto dolor nostrum voluptate quos consectetur facere, quia, earum non, tenetur, officia laboriosam cumque suscipit itaque nobis obcaecati. Facilis veritatis, repudiandae.p</p>
            </section>

<!-- Use any element to open the sidenav -->
    </body>
    <span onclick="openNav()">open</span>
</main>     

<!-- Use any element to open the sidenav -->
<span onclick="openNav()">open</span>

</html>
```

css file

```
/* Secciones */
html{
    margin-top: 0px;
    /*overflow: hidden; */

}

body{

   /*  overflow-x: hidden;*/
}

p{
    font-family: 'Lora';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
}

fieldset {
    font-family: 'Lora';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
}


 .nav_footer{
    height: 90%;
    background-color: black; /* Black*/
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    /*overflow-x: hidden; */

}

.nav_divididor{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #388E3C;
    height: 12px;

}


 .primera_section{
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF; /* Black*/
 }

 .segunda_section{
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    background-color: #C8E6C9; /* Black*/
 }

 .tercera_section{
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    background-color: #BDBDBD; /* Black*/
 }

 .divisoria {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    height: 2px;
 }

 .menu_burger{
    position: absolute;
    top:2;
 }





/* The side navigation menu */
.sidenav {
    height: 100%; /* 100% Full-height */
    width: 0; /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
    top: 0; /* Stay at the top */
    left: 0;
    background-color: white; /* Dark Green*/
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
    padding-top: 60px; /* Place content 60px from the top */
    transition: 0.8s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
}

.sidenav::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

/* The navigation menu links */
.sidenav a {
    font-family: 'Lora';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: black;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
.sidenav a:hover {
    color: grey;
}

/* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */
.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

/* Style page content - use this if you want to push the page content to the right when you open the side navigation */
#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 20px;
}

/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
    .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

Comment: Post your HTML code as well...

Comment: And your CSS as well, so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)